# How to get GitHub OAuth2 state code via curl to simulate Web Application Flow?

Tags: shell, curl, oauth, access-token, github-api

I'm trying to automate code export for few repositories at `code.google.com` into GitHub (before they [disappear in the next month](https://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/ReadOnlyTransition)!).

Here are the manual process to do that (e.g. for repo `foo`):

1. `https://code.google.com/export-to-github/request-export/foo`

   - this redirects to `https://github.com/login`
2. `https://code.google.com/export-to-github/start-export/foo`

   - the form should consist `code` and `state`
3. `https://code.google.com/export-to-github/confirm-export/foo`

So my approach is to submit form at `start-export` into `confirm-export` via `curl` with given `code` and `state`:

```
<form method="GET" action="/export-to-github/confirm-export/foo">
  <input type="text" hidden="true" name="code" value="GITHUB_CODE">
  <input type="text" hidden="true" name="state" value="FORM_STATE">
  <input class="maia-button" id="confirm-button" type="submit" value="Confirm" tabindex="1">
</form>
```

I already know how to get the last form state:

```
curl -s https://code.google.com/export-to-github/start-export/foo | grep -o 'state.\+value=.[^"]\+' | grep -o '[^"]\+$'
```

but I don't know how to get `code` value from GitHub API.

I've my GitHub credentials stored in `~/.secrets` as:

```
$ cat ~/.secrets 
export GITHUB_API_TOKEN=xyz
export GITHUB_CLIENT_ID=xyz
```

and they can be loaded by:

```
. ~/.secrets
```

And they works fine by the following test:

```
curl "https://api.github.com/user?access_token=$GITHUB_API_TOKEN"
```

Now I want to get the `state` string, see: [OAuth - Web Application Flow](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#web-application-flow):

> `state`   `string`    An unguessable random string. It is used to protect against cross-site request forgery attacks.

Seems this is designed for web application flow, it not generated in any of the following request (not even sure if that's the correct end-point for that):

```
curl "https://api.github.com/authorizations?access_token=$GITHUB_API_TOKEN"
```

gives the error:

> This API can only be accessed with username and password Basic Auth.

And the following requests:

```
curl "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?access_token=$GITHUB_API_TOKEN"
```

or:

```
curl "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?access_token=$GITHUB_API_TOKEN&client_id=$GITHUB_CLIENT_ID&amp;redirect_uri=https://code.google.com/export-to-github/start-export/foo&amp;scope=user:email,public_repo,notifications"
```

returns:

> You are being `<a href="https://github.com/login?return_to=%2Flogin%2Foauth%2Fauthorize%3Faccess_token%3DSOME_ACCESS_CODE_HERE">redirected</a>`

**Is there any non-web application flow or other workaround to get `state` which I can use in order to submit the form?**

Based on above I'm expecting something like:

```
curl -v --data "code=$GITHUB_STATE&state=$(grep -o 'state.\+value=.[^"]\+' https://code.google.com/export-to-github/start-export/foo | grep -o '[^"]\+$')" https://code.google.com/export-to-github/confirm-export/foo
```

however it currently returns the error:

> Error getting GitHub user.

because the `code` value is missing and I don't know how to get it from GitHub API in order to submit that form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the solution is to set `user_session` cookie. This can be fetched either from the web-browser (after one-off login) or by submitting user/password into GitHub login form, and get the right cookie.

Then this can be exported as:

```
export GITHUB_USER_SESSION=xyz
```

Now, the following Bash script is straight forward:

```
REPO="foo"
AUTH_PAGE=$(wget -qO- --header="Cookie: user_session=$GITHUB_USER_SESSION" "https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?access_token=$GITHUB_API_TOKEN&client_id=$GITHUB_CLIENT_ID&amp;redirect_uri=https://code.google.com/export-to-github/start-export/$REPO&amp;scope=user:email,public_repo,notifications")
STATE=$(echo $AUTH_PAGE | grep -o 'name=.\?state[^=]\+value=.[^>]\+')
CODE=$(echo $AUTH_PAGE | grep -o 'name=.\?code[^=]\+value=.[^>]\+')
curl --data "code=$(eval $CODE; echo $value)&state=$(eval $STATE; echo $value)" https://code.google.com/export-to-github/confirm-export/$REPO
```

In above code, the `$AUTH_PAGE` consist the source page after authentication (based on the user session) and it has the right `code` and `state` value set.

Optionally the page results can be stored into text file via `| html2text -o "$REPO.txt"` (after `html2text` is installed).